# Getting a Page via its post-name using WP REST API v2 and Postman

Tags: plugins, api, rest-api

Using Postman as a Chrome extension I have had success accessing Pages(not posts as I don't use them) from my WP website.

Having trouble pulling data using the post-name url that I set way back in the Permalinks.

Here is what I have:

- http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/43 (Actual ID page for 2012
  Happy Days SUCCESS)
- http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/happy-days (The permalink
  "post-name" doesn't work FAILURE. The page "happy-days" is the post-name permalink set up for that page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [`slug` argument](http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/pages/): `/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?slug=happy-days`

Comment: How to show list of pages same as post. For ex. this is how post archive shows `http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?page=1&per_page=10`. But how to show pages like this?